# Getting page() of the last row in power builder 12.5

Tags: powerbuilder, powerbuilder-2017

I tried to use Describe and Evaluate, however the result will always be one, what's wrong here?

I have a composite dw with two sub reports in it.

I set my footer height to 0, only set to 780 when it is in the last page of the report.

So I tried to get the total row in each report and get the page() of the last row in this way:

```
Long l_page
l_page = Long(dwc1.describe("Evaluate('PageCount()', 60)"))
```

idw_print is my composite dw, while dwc1 is my first report.

l_page will be the last page.

I set if l_page = pageCount(), then set height of footer, however, it doesn't help, other pages will reserved the spaces for footer as well.

Any idea on what's wrong here?